# error in sending mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Net.Mail;

```
public partial class adminEmail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string address = null;
    string to = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (address == null)
                address = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;

            else
                address = address + "," + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            Label2.Text = address;
            string to = address;
            txtTo.Text = to;
        }

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string from = ".com"; //Replace this with your own correct Gmail Address


        //Replace this with the Email Address to whom you want to send the mail

        Label1.Text = "Mail sent successfully";
        Label1.Visible = true;
        MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        Label2.Text = address;

       /*gettting error here*/ mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "Check My Ads", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = Editor1.ScriptPath;
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        //Add the Creddentials- use your own email id and password

        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");

        client.Port = 587; // Gmail works on this port
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail works on Server Secured Layer
        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception ex2 = ex;
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            while (ex2 != null)
            {
                errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
            }

        }
    }
    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

and my .aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="adminEmail.aspx.cs" Inherits="adminEmail" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
    TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>



<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div>
        <center>
            <table style="width: 652px; height: 504px">
                <tr>
                    <td   colspan="2">
                        <span style="color: activecaption"><strong><em><span style="font-size: 16pt">
                        Mail Sender</span></em></strong>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 26px" >
                        <strong><span style="color: activecaption">
                        Enter UserName</span></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align=left style="height: 26px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="169px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong><span style="color:Gray"><span style="color: activecaption">
                        Enter Password</span> </span></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align=left>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong><span style="color: activecaption">
                        To:</span></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align=left>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" Width="169px" Height="22px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong><span style="color: activecaption">
                        Subject:</span></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align=left>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong><span style="color: activecaption">
                        Body: </span></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" ButtonMouseOverBorderColor="GradientInactiveCaption" ButtonMouseOverColor="ActiveCaption" DialogButtonBarColor="ActiveCaption" DialogHeadingColor="ActiveCaption" DialogSelectedTabColor="ActiveCaption" DialogUnselectedTabColor="ActiveCaption" EditorBorderColor="ActiveCaption" SelectedTabBackColor="ActiveCaption" SelectedTabTextColor="InactiveCaptionText" TabBackColor="ActiveCaption" TabMouseOverColor="GradientActiveCaption" ToolbarColor="GradientActiveCaption" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="ActiveCaption" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                           <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="RESET" CausesValidation="False" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="ActiveCaption" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible=false></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            DataKeyNames="username" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="223px">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" ReadOnly="True" 
                                    SortExpression="username" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="emailid" HeaderText="emailid" 
                                    SortExpression="emailid" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="gender" 
                                    SortExpression="gender" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:eclassConnectionString2 %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [username], [emailid], [gender] FROM [userdetails] WHERE ([status_user] = @status_user)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="new" Name="status_user" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            </center>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

please do tell me what is my fault

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
/*gettting error here*/ mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
```

You've never set the value of `to` anywhere. In the `Page_Load` method, you have a local variable named `to` that hides the class member. Change your code to have an appropriate value and see how far you get.

Comment: still after coreecting my code the error is solved but my mails are not being sent..can any body tell me why..

Comment: @shweta, place break points and step through your code. You'll notice you are catching and essentially swallowing an exception. Figure out where your code is going by stepping through it, and you might see what is breaking. The idea is to narrow down the problem and then posting a question which allows someone to quickly provide an accurate response without having to look through a wall of code.

Comment: yes thank you .. i did it.. d thing was i was not using my correct password...  client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "tyita5230305");

Comment: @shweta, you may want to remove/mask your personal information from the code and comment. Don't post your email and password for the world to see!

Comment: but can you tell me to extract from body what should i do cause my body isnt being extracted what should i do?? as my body is sort of ajax editor tool

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `to` yet.

```
 /*gettting error here*/ mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
```

Try this:

```
 mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtTo.Text));
```

or

```
foreach(string toAddr in txtTo.Text.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddr));
}
```

Replace your 'send' code with this:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
    EnableSsl = true
};
client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "testSubject", "testbody");
```

Comment: but even after doing all these my mail isnt being sent......am i using the right way

Comment: client.Send(from,to,txtSubject.Text,Editor1.ToString()); getting error here System.InvalidOperationException: The SMTP host was not specified.